# Issue converting matrix to dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to look at some combinations. However, when I run the code that generates the combinations, the output looks like it is a matrix. I have tried to convert the matrix to a dataframe and it either crashes R or combines everything into one column. I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this.

Here is an example dataset

```
    structure(list(V1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Here is the code that I am using to create the combinations

```
library(arrangements)
two <- (combinations(b$V1, 2))
```

Here is what I was using to try and convert the data into a dataframe but everything just get combined into one column

```
two <- as.data.frame((combinations(b$V1, 2)))
```

So for this example above, I was hoping that the output would have two columns and three rows

I really need the output in a dataframe because I need to do some more downstream work on the output of the combinations

Comment: I understand the issue.  It isrelated to the class i.e. you have a factor column.  Convert to character and it works as expectedd

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you for identifying that. I will keep an eye out for that in the future.

Comment: For many functions, `factor` attribute can have a clash.  One reason why the default option changed in `read.table/read.csv` or` data.frame` creation from TRUE to FALSE for `stringsAsFactors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need as a `list`

```
as.data.frame(combn(as.character(b$V1), 2, simplify = FALSE))
```

---

In the OP's post, the column is `factor`.  It may need to be converted to `character`

```
 as.data.frame(combinations(as.character(b$V1), 2))
          V1         V2
1 AL033528.3     THRAP3
2 AL033528.3 AC106707.1
3 AL033528.3       LIPH
4     THRAP3 AC106707.1
5     THRAP3       LIPH
6 AC106707.1       LIPH
```

Comment: Yeah.. that solved the problem. I knew this was going to be a simple solution but I didn't realise it was going to be that simple

Comment: Will do! I will circle back in 8 minutes to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
data.frame(
  V1=t(combn(b$V1,2))[,1],
  V2=t(combn(b$V1,2))[,2])
```